# JPQL Query ManyToOne

Tags: sql, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, jpql

JPQL query for both **ManyToOne Unidirectional and Bidirectional Relationship**

---

```
    class ParentEntity{
      @Id
      String parentId1; //composite key
      @Id
      String parentId2;
      @ManyToOne
      ChildEntity childEntityRef;
    }
```

---

```
    class ChildEntity {  //ManyToOne Unidirectional Relationship case
      @Id
      String childId1;  //composite key
      @Id
      String childId2;
    }
    or
    class ChildEntity {  //ManyToOne Bidirectional Relationship case
      @Id
      String childId1;  //composite key
      @Id
      String childId2;
      @OneToMany
      List<ParentEntity> parentEntitiesref;
    }
```

---

```
_______________________________________________________________________
||        ParentEntity  Table              ||    ChildEntity Table     ||
||_________________________________________||__________________________||
parentId1|parentId2|childId1_FK|childId1_FK|| childId1| childId2       ||
||_______|_________|___________|___________||_________|________________||
|| p11   |p21      | c11       |c21        ||   c11   |    c21         ||
|| p12   |p22      | c11       |c21        ||   c12   |    c22         ||
|| p13   |p23      | c12       |c22        ||   c13   |    c23         ||
|| p14   |p24      | c12       |c22        ||         |                ||
||_______|_________|___________|___________||_________|________________||
```

I need JPQL query to access List of all childEntity that are not connected to particular ParentEntity (in both case Unidirectional and Bidirectional Relationship).

```
Example -
For ParentEntity[p11,p21] get All other disconnected List of ChildEntity([c12,c22],[c13,c23])
```

Best Regards,
Gaurav Gupta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c from ChildEntity c where c.childId != (
    select p.childEntityRef.childId from ParentEntity p where p.parentId = :parentId)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i have updated my question for composite key entity , may you help me in the composite key case case

Comment: Reloved with query "select c from ChildEntity c where c != (
    select p.childEntityRef from ParentEntity p where p.parentId = :parentId)